# Bootstrap css is not compatible with my code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to build a table having vertical headers by following this website: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Fapif

I also use bootstrap css.

The issue is bootstrap css are not compatible with the previous example:
https://jsfiddle.net/arj0k0j8/

my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            Newsletter generator v2
        </title>
        <style>
.table-header-rotated {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-header-rotated td {
  width: 30px;
}
 .table-header-rotated th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate {
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
      -ms-transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
          transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated th.row-header {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
    </style>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="container">
    <table class="table table-header-rotated">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
      <th></th>
      <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
      <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 2</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 3</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 4</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 5</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 6</span></div></th>
    </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 1</th>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column1"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row1-column2"></td>
      <td><input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row1-column3"></td>
      <td><input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row1-column4"></td>
      <td><input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row1-column5"></td>
      <td><input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row1-column6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 2</th>
      <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row2-column1"></td>
      <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column2"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row2-column3"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row2-column4"></td>
      <td><input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row2-column5"></td>
      <td><input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row2-column6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 3</th>
      <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row3-column1"></td>
      <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row3-column2"></td>
      <td><input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column3"></td>
      <td><input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row3-column4"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row3-column5"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row3-column6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I'm removing this line:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

everything works well

Comment: You will have to use your web console debugging tools to try to find elements that are not displaying properly, and then track down which style rules are causing conflict, and then work from there

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Bootstrap `.table` class from your table..

`<table class="table-header-rotated">`

http://codeply.com/go/V8djT7SOzD